Sci-fi book of short stories. In one, a space ship captain named Gunner Whaleman repeatedly used "shronk" to mean "understood"
Once read a sci fi (unsure if it was by Isaac Asimov or Ray Bradbury) containing short stories. In one, a space ship captain named Gunner Whaleman repeatedly used the term "shronk" to mean "understood".
Another story entitled Mars Products was about strangers in a small town opening up a store that sold items that were clearly not from earth. The story ends with police chasing the strangers in their car until they reach an airport runway where the car sprouts wings and flies away at high speed.
In a third story, a scientist becomes cornered by fire in a laboratory and, through will alone, transports himself to a safe part of the lab. He then learns to transport to other locations on earth and begins to teach others to transport. Soon after, the earth is covered in transport stations. The transportation technique is named "Jaunting". I think it may have been the basis for the film Jumper.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Are you sure this was one book?  The third story you're referring to is The Stars My Destination as answered here but it's a novel, and hasn't appeared in an anthology.

The second story is "The Martian Shop" by Howard Fast, as discussed here.

@DavidW - Jaunting was the subject of a short story; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Jaunt

@Valorum Sure, I know that one.  A jaunt takes an eternity if you're awake.  But the circumstances of a scientist who makes the first recorded jaunt as an emergency response to a fire is an exact match to TSMD.

"The Martian Shop" has been anthologized in A Decade of Science Fiction and Fantasy and collected in The Edge of Tomorrow (not to be confused with the Asimov collection of the same name), and none of the other stories in either collection match the other two stories here.

@DavidW You are on fire with the story ID! :) Nice!

The first story is The Guns of Terra 10 by Don Pendleton. It's a novel, not a short story and hasn't been collected in anything other than a collected work of Pendleton's own fiction. It's 'Skronk', by the way, not 'Shronk'.

Whaleman nodded. “Indoctrinated,” he assured her.
“Be kind to Reevers,” she reminded him. “Avoid if possible.”
“Skronk,” he said.

The second story is a fair description of The Martian Shop by Howard Fast. It's been repeatedly collected.

While the Fifth Avenue storefront is striking, it was done with the
type of expensive modesty that would do credit to Tiffany's. The last thing installed was the name of the shop itself, MARS PRODUCTS, in gold letters, each letter a half-inch in relief and five inches high. It has since been determined that these letters are cast out of solid gold.

The third story is a fair description of The Stars My Destination by Alfred Bester. Again, this is a full-length novel.

A researcher named Jaunte set fire to his bench and himself
(accidentally) and let out a yell for help, with particular reference
to a fire extinguisher. Who so surprised as Jaunte and his colleagues
when he found himself standing alongside said extinguisher, seventy
feet removed from his lab bench?


My guess is that if these were collected together in some fashion (noting that there are two full-length novels here, plus a fair length short story), it would have been in an unlicensed collection of fiction.

+1 Aside: A "shronk" is of course a most excellent play in the game of Fizbin.
